# Error installing Netbean in Windows 8

Tags: netbeans, java

I have tried everything possible to install Netbean 7.3.1 on my Windows 8 OS supporting laptop. However, it was not going through from here https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html.

This is the message I got after downloading all the software from mentioned link when tried to install for each download:

> CRITICAll nullnull

I downloaded JDK (Name of the file: jdk-7u25-nb-7_3_1-windows-x64) and when I tried installing JDK I got an error says:

> cannot find bundled JVM to run installer

Please can anyone share step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 2):

Open command prompt in the directory where your netbeans setup file is located. (to open cmd prompt, press shift and right click anywhere in the directory window and hit 'open command prompt here')
Now type the following command in command prompt

> netbeans-8.0-windows.exe --tempdir C:\Temp --userdir C:\NBI

hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229809), though not in netbeans.  Check out comments [9](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229809#c9) and [10](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229809#c10) for a possible work-around.

Comment: that says something about the exclamation mark in my user name. the location of my file is C:\Users\SUNNY!\Desktop.  At least i'm learning why this problem occurs thanks however i tried to rename the folder but it didn't let me. How am i suppose to any lead on this ?

Comment: Not sure if renaming your folder will necessarily rename your user; i'm assuming your user (with the exclamation) is defined in some property file or as a system variable, which the installer is using and crapping out.  Try a completely new user on your current machine?